Acer BIOS not showing USB boot drive
I am installing Arch Linux for the first time on an old Acer computer.
After rebooting multiple times, fixing a problem with the partitioning,  I encountered an issue with the BIOS: The BIOS did not list the usb drive in the boot menu.
I tried updating the BIOS, but that did not fix the problem.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem before, and do you know how to fix it?

What have you done to make the drives bootable, or not bootable? Did the drives ever show up in the BIOS as bootable, or is this a new problem and the system worked ok previously? What changes happened between things working and not working. Please note that your question lacks the detail necessary for us to understand the basic problem or the context within which it occurs.

Previously the drives showed up as bootable, and the system worked ok.

That's part of one of the questions I asked you. Please note that I am also suggesting things that should be present in your question in order to help myself and others here better understand the problem you are facing and what you need. So add any answers to these questions to your main post using the EDIT button. I recommend that you read the HELP section to better understand how this site works.

I am very well aware of how this site works, I was in the process of answering the rest of your questions.

I had to reboot the computer multiple times to solve a problem with the partitioning. Afterwards, the bios stopped recognizing the usb boot drives.

Does the USB work on another computer? In my experience, USB drives are flaky when it comes to showing as bootable devices, and I've often had to reload the bootable image on these. If you recreate this bootable USB does it still not show in the BIOS? If you confirm this (or another) USB shows as bootable on a different computer, does that same USB that works on the other computer still not show on yours?

I have reloaded the usb image 3 times without it being shown in the bios, and i have tried it with different usbs.


Use smaller drives when available, e.g., 8 or 16 GB. 2. Be sure the USB drive is formatted FAT32. 3. Try making the bootable drive a different way, e.g., Rufus or ohters at https://alternativeto.net/software/rufus/


Please use fdisk and verify, that all the conditions for booting are still fulfilled.

Using Rufus fixed the problem.
